# How can I remove the light from this recessed fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, kitchens, replacement

I have recessed lights in my kitchen and all but one went out. It is a gimbal light that rotates left to right. I pulled the recessed light housing down but there's no way to open and remove the bulb (that I know of). Can someone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lights are sealed. There is no bulb, just an electronic board with tiny LEDs mounted on it.

You have to replace the unit. So buy a decent brand.

If you want a replacement bulb then they have to be traditional style.  You can check yourself when you are in the store.  Or, if online, ask the store.

Note, generally it is cheaper to get a sealed unit.  It also tends to diffuse the light better.  But, throwing away the whole sealed unit every 3-7 years is wasteful.

If you get a bulb, then either the driver is built into the bulb making it bigger or, you have to use an external driver.  This is definitely the greener way to go.

I am in a different country from you, so I can't recommend any brand - which would also make it off-topic.

In my house built in 2017, I struggled with this and eventually went with the sealed units because they were half the price as compared to a fixture and bulb.  But I went with the most expensive local brand.  I have 120+ units and 3-6 die every year.  The supplier stands behind them and replaces them for free.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, and new questions shouldn't be posed in comments.